# JPQL Statement Invalid unbound variable "serial_number" in query

Tags: java, jpql, openjpa

How can i make this work? I want to count serial number with a value of 1? Thanks guys i am a beginner.

```
serial_Number = 1;


Query query = (Query) es.em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(p.serial_Number) FROM Product p where p.product_Id = serials_Number");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
   Query query = (Query) es.em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(p.serial_Number) FROM Product p where p.product_Id =:serial_Number").setParameter("serial_Number", serial_Number);
```

Then use..

```
query.getSingleResult();
```

to get the singular entity.

Comment: tnx. by the way i am using this for checking if the recordexist or not :)

Comment: You can use a parameter just like "...where x = " + variable; but you can easily leave yourself open to SQL injections

Comment: is that a bad design? sql injections?